# Cannot bulk load because the file "‎⁨\\file-name.csv could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am aware of other links that do exist suggesting that the file should be

1. On a UNC Path
2. It should have proper permissions. I have permissions set to `full-control` for everyone under the security tab.

Also, I thought that if I go under advanced> share tab then I would have more control over how to set up permissions for this folder when it is a UNC Share but it says that `The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed`

Anyways, still when I pass the file to a stored procedure as a bulk-insert input then it simply throws following error:

`Cannot bulk load because the file "‎⁨\\ussd-file\users\transfer\kdesai\bulk-insert.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).`

is there anything else I can/should try to reoslve this issue?

Comment: I very much suspect that the service account SQL Server is running under doesn't have access. Rather than giving everyone access, explicitly give the SQL Server Service account access to the share, and relevant directories.

Comment: The thought crossed my mind but then I thought that everyone should include that account. Let me try that. Also, should I just give access to that account in security tab or also in advanced>Share tab as well ? Because the problem here is that I do not see that I can change anything on that tab.

Comment: My knowledge of how to set permissions is limited; I leave that to my Network Administrator so that I don[t break anything.